# how to hide a ImageButton According to dataField value using ASPX web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webforms, aspxgridview

After checking a condition I want to hide or view an image button inside a `gridView`.
I tried to like this. but it is not working.

```
                         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            EnableModelValidation="True" DataKeyNames="T_ID" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                            OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <Columns>
                               
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TEMPL_TITLE" HeaderText="Title">
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TEMPL_DESC" HeaderText="Description">
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="CAT_NAME" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Workflow Type" DataField="WFTYPE_DESCRIPTION" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Owner" DataField="EMP_CALLING_NAME" />
                                
                                 <%# if(Eval("EXP_PENDING_APPR").ToString() == "0") { %>
                                  <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ViewImageButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TEMPL_ID") %>'
                                            ImageUrl="Images/jdAttView.gif" OnCommand="btnViewTemplate_Click" ToolTip="View and download template" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <% } %>
                            </Columns>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                No templates have been assigned to you security capabilites, Please contact your
                        local administrator for more information.
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

The error with this code
[The error with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YWdx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply condition on server control itself.
 `<asp:ImageButton  Visible='<%# Eval("EXP_PENDING_APPR").ToString().Equals("0")  %>'  ID="ViewImageButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TEMPL_ID") %>' ImageUrl="Images/jdAttView.gif" OnCommand="btnViewTemplate_Click" ToolTip="View and download template" />`